# Jquery validation not allow zero in input field

Tags: jquery, validation

How can I disallow a user to enter zero into an input field? I am using the Jquery validation plugin, and the number validation method. I would like a user to be able to enter positive and negative numbers and disallow zero's.

i have tried using the greaterThan and lessThan methods, but I cannot seem to get them to work properly.

```
     $("#CPO_AddItemForm").validate({
        errorElement: "em",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent("div").next("div"));
        },
        rules: {
            Stockno: {required: true, nowhitespace: true},
            Descrip: "required",
            Item_Qty: {required: true, number: true, greaterThan: 0},
            Price: {required: true, number: true},
            Unit: "required",
            Vac_Occ: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            Stockno: {required: "Required"},
            Descrip: {required: "Required"},
            Item_Qty: {required: "Required"},
            Price: {required: "Required"},
            Unit: {required: "Required"},
            Vac_Occ: {required: "Required"},
        },

    });
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the notEqual rule... http://theprofessionguru.com/article/jquery-validate-js-check-value-is-not-equal-to-zero

Comment: Of course, in reading further down that post, it's a custom rule that he's defining -- but you can easily define that same rule. ;)

Comment: that worked perfectly.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$.validator.addMethod("notOnlyZero", function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || parseInt(value) > 0;
});

$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        yourFieldName: {
            notOnlyZero: '0'
        }
    },
    messages: {
        yourFieldName: {
            notOnlyZero: 'Message to show'
        }
    }
});
```